# how to send selected country name from dropdown to spring mvc with angular js

Tags: angularjs

Here I have country list dropdown and I want to send selected country name and country code (which is coming from URL in JSON format) to spring controller with post URL. But in my case only countrycode is going through URL to spring controller. Can anyone help please ..

```
    <form data-ng-submit="submit()" data-ng-controller="MyController">
    <h3>{{headerText}}</h3>
            {{formData}}<br> <br>
            <div data-ng-init="getCountry()">

                <select id="countrylist"
                    style="border-radius: 10px; width: 210px; height: 40px"
                    data-ng-model="Countryselected"
                    data-ng-options="country .cntryName for country in getCountries"
                    data-ng-click="getCity()">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <select style="border-radius: 10px; width: 210px; height: 40px"
                    data-ng-model="cityselect" data-ng-disabled="!Countryselected"
                    data-ng-options=" c.cityName for c in availableCities "
                    data-ng-click="getPlace()">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p>{{Countryselected}}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{{cityselect}}</p>
            </div>
            <div>

                    <pre>Form data ={{list}}</pre>

<input type="text" id="tags" data-ng-model="placeselected"
            data-ng-keydown="complete()" placeholder="Type place name"> <br>
        <!--         <select style="border-radius: 10px; width: 210px; height: 40px" data-ng-model="placeselected"  data-ng-options=" x.answer for x in availablePlaces "> -->
        <!--                   <option value="">place</option> -->
        <!--                 </select> -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app
                    .controller(
                            'MyController',
                            function($scope, $http) {

                            $scope.getCountry = function() {

                                $http(
                                        {
                                            method : 'GET',
                                            url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/newclue/country/list'
                                        }).success(
                                        function(data, status, headers,
                                                config) {
                                            $scope.getCountries = data;
                                        }).error(
                                        function(data, status, headers,
                                                config) {
                                            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                            // or server returns response with an error status.
                                        });
                            };
                            $scope.getCity = function() {
                                $scope.availableCities = [];

                                $http(
                                        {
                                            method : 'GET',
                                            url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/newclue/city/list'
                                        }).success(
                                        function(data, status, headers,
                                                config) {
                                            $scope.getCities = data;
                                        }).error(
                                        function(data, status, headers,
                                                config) {
                                            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                            // or server returns response with an error status.
                                        });
                                angular
                                        .forEach(
                                                $scope.getCities,
                                                function(value) {
                                                    if (value.countrycode.cntryCode == $scope.Countryselected.cntryCode) {
                                                        $scope.availableCities
                                                                .push(value);
                                                    }

                                                });
                            };
//                              $scope.contry = angular.copy.Countryselected;
//                              $scope.city = angular.copy.cityselect;

                            //   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
                            $scope.getPlace = function() {
                                $scope.complete = function()

                                {
                                    $scope.availablePlaces = [];

                                    $http(
                                            {
                                                method : 'GET',
                                                url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/newclue/clue_answer/list'
                                            }).success(
                                            function(data, status, headers,
                                                    config) {

                                                $scope.getPlaces = data;
                                            }).error(
                                            function(data, status, headers,
                                                    config) {
                                                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                                // or server returns response with an error status.
                                            });

                                    angular
                                            .forEach(
                                                    $scope.getPlaces,
                                                    function(value) {
                                                        if (value.citycode.cityCode == $scope.cityselect.cityCode) {
                                                            $scope.availablePlaces
                                                                    .push(value.answer);
                                                        }

                                                    });

                                    $("#tags").autocomplete(

                                    {

                                        source : $scope.availablePlaces
                                    });

                                }

                            };

                            $scope.list = [];
                            $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';
                            $scope.submit = function() {


                                var formData = { 
                                        cntryName: $scope.Countryselected.cntryName,
                                         cntryCode: $scope.Countryselected.cntryCode


                                };

                                alert("Hello2--->"+formData.cntryName);
                                var response = $http
                                        .post(
                                                'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/newclue/PostFormData',
                                                 formData);

                                response.success(function(data, status,
                                        headers, config) {
                                    alert("hello3--"+data.cntryCode);


                                    $scope.list.push(data);
                                });
                                response.error(function(data, status,
                                        headers, config) {
                                    alert("Exception details: "
                                            + JSON.stringify({
                                                data : data
                                            }));
                                });

                                //Empty list data after process
                                $scope.list = [];

                            };

                        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll get the best results from this site if you invest time in crafting your question. Try to make it as minimal as you can that still reproduces your issue - see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to style it in an way that makes it easy to see the code without scrolling a lot (or ideally, at all).

Comment: You should try first to reduce your example to as less code as possible. This will help you figure out the problem and will help us to quicker understand what you are doing. What did you try so far to solve the problem?

Comment: You should create a jsFiddle instead for better understandings. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Show us your JSON object getCountries.

Comment: [{"cntryCode":1,"cntryName":"India"},{"cntryCode":2,"cntryName":"Australia"},{"cntryCode":3,"cntryName":"Pakistan"},{"cntryCode":4,"cntryName":"America"}]

Comment: How can i put it in jsfiddle. i am doing it with spring controller and database.

Answer (score 0):

change ng-options like this:

```
data-ng-options="country as country.cntryName for country in getCountries"
```

Comment: still  country name is coming null in html page and spring controller console. But country_code which is another attribute of country object is coming properly.